# Stripe exception thrown when creating new connect account with bank account

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

After upgrading to the latest version of Stripe.Net.
I'm trying to create a new custom connect account, which includes a bank account, with the .Net API and Stripe is throwing this exception.

> This account can only be updated with an account token, because it was originally created with an account token.  (Attempted to update param 'account_token' directly.)

I'm assigning the AccountToken I'm generating from Stripe.js and that seems to be generating ok. Additionally I have no issue adding an external bank to a already created connect account. I just can't seem to create a new custom account

Here is my c# code

```
                AccountDobOptions dobOptions = new AccountDobOptions()
                {
                    Day = yogaProfile.Birthdate.Day,
                    Month = yogaProfile.Birthdate.Month,
                    Year = yogaProfile.Birthdate.Year
                };

                AddressOptions addressOptions = new AddressOptions()
                {
                    City = bankDetails.City,
                    Country = bankDetails.CountryCode,
                    State = bankDetails.CountryCode == "US" ? bankDetails.USStateCode : bankDetails.NonUSStateCode,
                    PostalCode = bankDetails.PostalCode,
                    Line1 = bankDetails.AddressLine1,
                    Line2 = bankDetails.AddressLine2
                };

                AccountLegalEntityOptions legal = new AccountLegalEntityOptions();
                legal.Dob = dobOptions;
                legal.Type = "individual";
                legal.Address = addressOptions;
                legal.FirstName = accountFullName.Split(' ')[0];
                legal.LastName = accountFullName.Split(' ')[1];

                //legal.SSNLast4 = bankDetails.LastFourSSN;


                AccountTosAcceptanceOptions tosOptions = new AccountTosAcceptanceOptions()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Ip = clientIpAddress != null ? clientIpAddress : GetUserIpAddress()
                };

                var accountOptions = new AccountCreateOptions()
                {
                    Email = yogaProfile.ApplicationUser.Email,
                    Type = AccountType.Custom,
                    Country = bankDetails.CountryCode,
                    LegalEntity = legal,
                    TosAcceptance = tosOptions,
                    AccountToken = stripeToken,
                    //TransferScheduleInterval = "weekly",
                    ExternalBankAccount = new AccountBankAccountOptions()
                };

                var accountService = new AccountService();
                Account account = accountService.Create(accountOptions);
```

Comment: Hi, the AccountToken is not a `Bank Account Token` but an actual `Account token` generated from `Legal Entity` [0]. 

You could pass the token to `ExternalAccountId` to  `AccountCreateOptions` to create the external account instead



* [0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_account?lang=node

Comment: the doc says I can use my secret key to create account tokens, so I tried that and passed the stripe token as the externalaccount id, but that throws an error saying "Invalid request (check your POST parameters): unable to determine value for parameter: external_account. For assistance, please email support@stripe.com."

Comment: I can successfully create a connect account then a external bank account, but I can't do them both in one create call to Stripe! Has this changed in the latest API?